# looking for patterns in binary columns r

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio, binary-data

I need to find and count the ID's that appear with a 1 after 3 or more consecutive zeros.

This is a example of what I have:

```
#  ID   Jan  Feb Mar  Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sept Oct
#   1   0    0   0    1   0   0   1   1    1    0
#   2   0    0   0    0   0   0   1   0    0    0
#   3   0    0   0    0   0   0   0   0    0    1
#   4   1    0   0    1   0   1   0   1    0    1
#   5   0    0   1    0   0   1   1   0    0    1

c1<- c("ID","Jan","Feb", "Mar","Apr", "May","Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct")
c2<-  c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0)
c3<- c(2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
c4<- c(3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
c5<- c(4,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
c6<- c(5,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1)
BD<-data.frame(rbind(c2,c3,c4,c5,c6))
colnames(BD)<-c1
```

The result of what I expect is something like this:

```
#  ID   Jan  Feb Mar  Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sept Oct
#   1   0    0   0    1   0   0   1   1    1    0
#   2   0    0   0    0   0   0   1   0    0    1
#   3   0    0   0    0   0   0   0   0    0    1
```

Anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: your output looks like `head(df, 3)` of input example to me

Comment: What if a row is `c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1)`? Should that be in the output or no? (i.e., does a 1 after 3 0s count if the zeros started after the first element)

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Yes, that row should be in the output too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collapse to string and use `grep()` to search for pattern.

```
k <- 3

grep(sprintf(paste0("%0", k + 1, "d"), 1), apply(d[-1], 1, paste, collapse=""))
# [1] 2 4 5 6 8
```

If no following 1 is needed you could use the `rle()`.

```
d
#     id Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
# c1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0
# c2   2   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
# c3   3   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0
# c4   4   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
# c5   5   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1
# c6   6   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
# c7   7   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1
# c8   8   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1
# c9   9   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0
# c10 10   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1

k <- 3
d$id[sapply(as.data.frame(t(d[-1])), function(x) any(rle(x)$lengths[rle(x)$values == 0] >= k))]
# [1] 2 4 5 6 8
```

*Data:*

```
set.seed(0)
d <- data.frame(id=1:10, 
                  `dimnames<-`(matrix(sample(0:1, 120, r=1), 10), 
                               list(paste0("c", 1:10), month.abb)))
```

Comment: Try with `d[1, 1:4] <- 0` and the first row's won't be returned as part of the output, although it should be. (This checks for exactly 3 0s and won't return the id of rows with >3 0s followed by a 1.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan True! Now better?

Comment: Now try with `d[1, 10:13] <- 0` and the first row's id is returned, but should not be. (this doesn't check if it's followed by a 1, so the 0s can be at the end)

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Oh, you're right I completely missed the point! Found another shorter solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you take the `rowid(rleid(x))` of a vector `x` you get the number of steps into each "run" each element is*. You can check that this is >= 3 and the element is 0. If that is true for the previous element (for the shifted output) and the element is 1, return TRUE. Then check if this is TRUE for `any` of the elements in the row.

```
library(data.table)

rows <- 
  apply(BD, 1, function(r) any(shift(rowid(rleid(r)) >= 3 & r == 0) & r == 1))

BD[rows,]
#    ID Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sept Oct
# c2  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1    1   0
# c3  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0    0   0
# c4  3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0   1
```

* Here's an example for a particular row (the first)

```
rbind(
  rowid_rleid = rowid(rleid(unlist(BD[1,]))),
  original = unlist(BD[1,]))

#             ID Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sept Oct
# rowid_rleid  1   1   2   3   1   1   2   1   2    3   1
# original     1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1    1   0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I have additional id information in other columns, so how can I apply this in specific columns? for example, in columns [2:14]?

Comment: You can change the `BD` in apply to `BD[2:14]`

Answer (score 1):

You can consolidate the rows into strings and use a regular expression to match '0001':

```
library(tidyverse)
rows = BD %>% 
  purrr::pmap(function(...) paste0(list(...)[-1], collapse='')) %>% 
  stringr::str_detect('0001')
BD[rows,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution that can make it

```
BDout <- subset(BD,apply(BD[-1], 1, function(x) head(which(x==1),1))>3)
```

such that

```
> BDout
  ID Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sept Oct
1  1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1    1   0
2  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0    0   0
3  3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0   1
```

Comment: Note this won't catch rows with 0001 if that pattern is preceded by a 1. e.g  if a row started with `c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1)`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan you mean a row of length 5, including ID?

Comment: Sorry, I meant if a row of `BD[-1]` started with those 5 elements (regardless of what the rest are) `head(which(x==1),1) > 3` would be FALSE, even though the row contained a 1 preceded by 3 0s. Another example would be if `BD[2, 2]` was changed to 1. Then the second row still contains a 1 preceded by 3 0s, but would not be in the output according to this formula.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan but that is not the case "a 1 after 3 or more consecutive zeros"...my understand of OP's question is that the number of leading zeros should be more than 3....

Comment: Consider if `BD[2, 2]` was 1. Then there's a 1 after 5 0s (in the July column) but the row would not be in the output according to this method.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan maybe the OP needs to clarify the objective of this question...counting leading zeros and counting run length of zeros are different for sure...

Comment: @IceCreamToucan yes, now I see

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table` to melt and filter for rows that match conditions.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(BD)[ID %in%
    melt(BD, id.vars="ID")[, 
        mth := .GRP, variable][
            value==1L, ID[mth[1L]>3L | any(diff(mth) > 3L)], ID]$V1
]
```

It should be faster for large datasets with sparse data.